# Extract XML tag data based on attributes of a different tag

Tags: python, xml

I'm working with xml.etree to parse a few enormous XML files that I need to import into a database with Python, but for some reason I can't figure out how I can extract a specific tag based on an attribute of a different tag

For example, in this piece of XML included below, I need to extract the text of the  tags that are under the NicamWarningCS  tags, and put both of them in a single list. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

```
<Main xmlns:mpeg7="urn:mpeg:mpeg7:schema:2001" xmlns="urn:tva:metadata:2004">
  <ProgramDescription>
    <ProgramInformationTable>
      <ProgramInformation programId="123456">
        <BasicDescription>
           <Genre href="urn:tva:metadata:cs:2004:2.4">
             <Name xml:lang="NL"><![CDATA[Film]]></Name>
           </Genre>
           <Genre href="urn:po:metadata:cs:GenreCS:2009:4" type="other">
             <Name xml:lang="NL"><![CDATA[Film]]></Name>
           </Genre>
           <Genre href="urn:po:metadata:cs:NicamWarningCS:2007:t">
             <Name xml:lang="NL"><![CDATA[Grof taalgebruik]]></Name>
           </Genre>
           <Genre href="urn:po:metadata:cs:NicamWarningCS:2007:g">
             <Name xml:lang="NL"><![CDATA[Geweld]]></Name>
           </Genre>
           <Genre href="urn:po:metadata:cs:GenreCS:2009:23" type="other">
             <Name xml:lang="NL"><![CDATA[Biography/Drama/History]]></Name>
           </Genre>
         </BasicDescription>
       </ProgramInformation>
     </ProgramInformationTable>
   </ProgramDescription>
 </Main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a detailed procedure of what I'd do :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# 1. Parse your xml file
tree = ET.parse('your.xml')

# 2. Get the root
root = tree.getroot()

# 3. Set the tag and attribute you are looking for
ns = 'urn:tva:metadata:2004'
matchTag = 'NicamWarningCS'

# 4. retrieve all Genres
genres = root.find('{%s}ProgramDescription' % ns) \
    .find('{%s}ProgramInformationTable' % ns) \
    .find('{%s}ProgramInformation' % ns) \
    .find('{%s}BasicDescription' % ns) \
    .findall('{%s}Genre' % ns)

# 5. filter them in order to get just the Names of the ones that match your matchTag : 'NicamWarningCS'
filteredGenreNames = [genre.find('{%s}Name' % ns) for genre in genres if matchTag in genre.get('href')]

# 6. extract the text of the tags
data = [t.text for t in filteredGenreNames]

print(data)
# ['Grof taalgebruik', 'Geweld']
```

Comment: I think this answer is more readable then the solution that I found, and nicely shows the solution proposed by Erik. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just get all `Genre` elements and filter the ones that have an `href` attribute you're interested in:

```
ns = 'urn:tva:metadata:2004'
all_genres = fromstring(xml) \
    .find('{%s}ProgramDescription' % ns) \
    .find('{%s}ProgramInformationTable' % ns) \
    .find('{%s}ProgramInformation' % ns) \
    .find('{%s}BasicDescription' % ns) \
    .findall('{%s}Genre' % ns)
some_genres = [g for g in all_genres if 'NicamWarningCS' in g.get('href')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get Erik's answer quickly up and running, but it hinted me in the direction of a different solution that managed to solve my problem.

By creating a dict with all genres in it, I was able to filter out all the Nicam warnings and add them to a list which I could then use to populate my SQL statements:

```
genreitemdict = dict()
for genreitem in program.iter("{urn:tva:metadata:2004}Genre"):
    for child in genreitem:
        genreitemdict[genreitem.attrib['href']] = child.text
        NicamWarningCS = [v for k, v in genreitemdict.items() if 'NicamWarningCS' in k]
print NicamWarningCS
```

It might not be the nicest solution, but for now this will do.